# Find collatie utf8mb4 with _ci_as in my db

Tags: mysql, character, collation, utf8mb4

I want to use utf8mb4, CI (case insensitive) and AS (accent-sensitive). Which can I choose? Specially for names in different languages, so accents are important.
I cannot find an _as option. And _bin is CS, and I need CI.

Help!?

My only options at the hosting company are: :

utf8mb4 (UTF-8 Unicode)
utf8mb4_bin Unicode (meertalig), Binair
utf8mb4_croatian_ci Kroatisch, ongevoelig voor hoofdletters
utf8mb4_croatian_mysql561_ci    Kroatisch
utf8mb4_czech_ci    Tsjechisch, ongevoelig voor hoofdletters
utf8mb4_danish_ci   Deens, ongevoelig voor hoofdletters
utf8mb4_esperanto_ci    Esperanto, ongevoelig voor hoofdletters
utf8mb4_estonian_ci Estisch, ongevoelig voor hoofdletters
utf8mb4_general_ci  Unicode (meertalig), ongevoelig voor hoofdletters
utf8mb4_german2_ci  Duits (Telefoonboek), ongevoelig voor hoofdletters
utf8mb4_hungarian_ci    Hongaars, ongevoelig voor hoofdletters
utf8mb4_icelandic_ci    IJslands, ongevoelig voor hoofdletters
utf8mb4_latvian_ci  Lets, ongevoelig voor hoofdletters
utf8mb4_lithuanian_ci   Litouws, ongevoelig voor hoofdletters
utf8mb4_myanmar_ci  onbekend, ongevoelig voor hoofdletters
utf8mb4_persian_ci  Perzisch, ongevoelig voor hoofdletters
utf8mb4_polish_ci   Pools, ongevoelig voor hoofdletters
utf8mb4_roman_ci    West-Europees, ongevoelig voor hoofdletters
utf8mb4_romanian_ci Roemeens, ongevoelig voor hoofdletters
utf8mb4_sinhala_ci  Singalees, ongevoelig voor hoofdletters
utf8mb4_slovak_ci   Slowaaks, ongevoelig voor hoofdletters
utf8mb4_slovenian_ci    Sloveens, ongevoelig voor hoofdletters
utf8mb4_spanish2_ci Traditioneel Spaans, ongevoelig voor hoofdletters
utf8mb4_spanish_ci  Spaans, ongevoelig voor hoofdletters
utf8mb4_swedish_ci  Zweeds, ongevoelig voor hoofdletters
utf8mb4_thai_520_w2 Thais
utf8mb4_turkish_ci  Turks, ongevoelig voor hoofdletters
utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci  Unicode (meertalig)
utf8mb4_unicode_ci  Unicode (meertalig), ongevoelig voor hoofdletters
utf8mb4_vietnamese_ci   Vietnamees, ongevoelig voor hoofdletters

Comment: There's no accent sensitive collation yet.

Answer (score 0):

The hosting company needs to upgrade to MySQL 8.0, at which point, there is one choice: utf8mb4_0900_as_ci, which handles all known character sets, but may or may not handle a specific country's quirks.

There are also several as_cs.